# Compilation error for HelloGluon example using Maven Client

Tags: java, maven, gluon

I do not understand what is happening when I try to compile HelloGluon example. (I just installed last version from repository)

mvn javafx:run succeeds.

mvn client:build gives:

```
Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:client-maven-plugin:0.1.33:compile (default-cli) on project hellogluon: Error: graalvm-ce-java11-20.2.0/bin/java -version failed to return a valid value for GraalVM.
```

If I do on command line:

```
graalvm-ce-java11-20.2.0/bin/java -version
```

I get the answer:

```
openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14

OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 20.2.0 (build 11.0.8+10-jvmci-20.2-b03)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 20.2.0 (build 11.0.8+10-jvmci-20.2-b03, 
mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Setting the GRAAL_HOME variable fixed it for me.

https://www.graalvm.org/docs/getting-started-with-graalvm/windows/

example: `setx /M GRAALVM_HOME "C:\Program Files\graalvm\graalvm-ce-java11-20.2.0"`